# Size of subelement not suit to parent WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am facing following issue. I have main window defined as

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="500"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6">
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1></local:UserControl1>
</Grid>
```

and UserControl1 as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication6.UserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
mc:Ignorable="d" Width="500" Height="650">
```

The Width and Height of both are the same so I would expect to see the whole view UserControl but it turns out to go beyond parent's size.

[image]

Is it because Window Height and Width comprise border?

Answer (score 0):

The height and width of the Window include the borders and title bar.

In general: do not use absolute sizes but use stretching instead by either setting Horizontal/VerticalAlignment to stretch or by nesting in a Grid.

To size elements in the Visual Studio designers use `d:DesignWidth` and `d:DesignHeight`. These do not affect the UI at application runtime.

Comment: If I set main window width and height I need to set as well usercontrol's size in order to have its visible representation during design time.

Comment: @Maximus - No, just nest it in a Grid. The grid will stretch the usercontrol (unless you set explicit sizes in the user control). For the window and usercontrol use DesignHeight and DesignWidth to be able to edit them in their designers

Comment: @Maximus You can set `d:DesignWidth` and `d:DesignHeight` to have a specific size when the UserControl is displayed in Visual Studio's designer.